# When can you copy/paste whole apps or games?

Tags: windows, gaming, portable

Is it possible to know when certain apps / games in Windows can be copy/pasted/moved without issues and when you cannot?

Why can I install a game like Diablo 3 from a CD and move its directory but the same action break another program? Coming from Mac OS X, I'm trying to figure out if there's a rule or pattern to how installs are handled in Windows.

Comment: -1:  This question lacks any indication of research effort.  Additionally, any attempt at an answer would likely be run into pages of content.

Comment: Hmm really?  Why is the question not 'proper'?  There are a few similar questions here about moving apps to another hdd and such, but no answers that give insight into discerning when its safe to move an app / game.

Why does it appear that I can launch games copied over to a new computer but can't do the same for apps, when both do appear to interact with the registry and have uninstall entries in windows?

Comment: I didn't call the question improper.  You are asking a lot of questions such that it's unclear what you're actually asking.  Then, there's the fairly clear lack of research, which would be exhibited by "I searched for [X], and found [Y,Z,P,D, and Q], but I'm still unclear on [X.1, X.2, and X.3]"  Finally, I quote myself, "any attempt at an answer would likely run into pages of content".

Comment: The question is not proper. This (like all the other [se] sites) is a *question and answer* site (note the singular), not a *many questions at once that are really vague and broad in scope* site.

Answer (score 2):

Some programs can be copied to a new location, some can not.  The reason they do not work when copied can be varied.  Most commonly, it is a registry issue.  The installer creates entries in the registry which specifies the location of certain files, folders, drives, etc.  Moving the installation will not modify the registry.  The same goes for application created configuration files.

You *can* often modify the registry and configuration files after the fact.  Sometimes this is an easy task.  Sometimes, it can be difficult if the developer doesnt make it obvious where all the files/entries are and how to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

At a very basic level...a very large number of things you access on a Windows machine must be installed. Installation usually allows a number of items to be written to a variety of directories and registry keys. This means if you move the executable (program) it will look for the items in the directories it wrote to when installed. If they are not there then the program will not run. When you reload your machine you almost always, must install the games and programs again that you want to use. For the second part of your question.....You do not need to keep your applications in the Program Files directory, which is usually the default installation directory of any installation. However usually you must select custom installation or watch for the screen that specifies the installation directory so you can change where it is installed. You can not just move things out of the Program Files directory to a new directory.